# Python version on machine vs version on shared environment

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code

python novice here.

I have python 3.8.5 on my new machine. The shared environment I've been working on is using python 3.7.1. I experienced json errors and numpy errors trying to run a script that worked on my old machine through VS Code (same environment).

My question is - Does the version of python on my machine have to match the version of python in the shared environment?

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated. I tried troubleshooting by reinstalling my environment and pandas. Did not work :(

Comment: In most cases, yes. A rule of thumb is that some libraries only support Python XX version. In the ideal case, your Python version should match the shared environment's version.

Comment: So your new machine uses 3.8, the shared env uses 3.7, but what did your _old_ machine use? Newer versions of Python 3 will run older code just fine, provided it's pure Python code. If it's code that relies on third party modules you'll need to make sure you have compatible versions installed, and those may or may not have different APIs from one version to the next.  Instead of asking folks to guess, show a [mcve] of code that works on the old system, and doesn't work on the new one. With the errors you're getting too, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Ensuring that your development environment version matches your production or shared environment version is crucial for your code to function correctly, as it is a frequent cause of errors leading to statements like "But it worked on my local machine!"

To address this, tools such as conda and pyenv enable you to maintain multiple python versions on your local machine simultaneously, enabling you to easily switch between them based on the particular project.

```
conda create --name project-env-for-personal python=3.7

conda create --name project-env-for-officejob python=3.5
```